# Выбор чекбокса и смена картинки

Tags: html, css

Есть набор цветов. Нужно чтобы при выборе одного из цветов, менялась картинка. В голову пришла идея реализовать с помощью невидимых чекбоксов, но реализация хромает. Либо блока с цветом не видно, либо виден и блок, и чекбокс.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.colors {
  width: 63px;
  height: 462px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #fdfdfd 0%, #e4e4e4 100%);
}

.button-colors {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color-red {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff4b4b -0.17%, #d80101 100.17%);
}

.color-green {
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, #00cc14 -0.43%, #10fe28 100.43%);
}

.color-blue {
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, #1fa2ff -0.69%, #12d8fa 46.71%, #a6eaff 99.31%);
}

.color-pink {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #fc70ff -9.13%, #f92abf 100.08%);
}

.color-yellow {
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, #f09819 -0.24%, #ffe501 99.76%);
}

.color-purple {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #7133f5 0.08%, #5b27c9 100.08%);
}

.plus {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  background: white;
}

.icon-plus {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.button-colors:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layout__wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-end">
        <div class="colors d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
          <input type="radio" name="droid" class="button-colors color-red" />
          <div class="button-colors color-green">
            <input type="radio" name="droid" />
          </div>
          <div class="button-colors color-blue"></div>
          <div class="button-colors color-pink"></div>
          <div class="button-colors color-yellow"></div>
          <div class="button-colors color-purple"></div>
          <div class="button-colors plus">
            <svg class="icon-plus">
                  <use xlink:href="/assets/images/icons.svg#plus"></use>
                </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 preview">
        <img src="./assets/images/preview1.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если цвет можно выбрать только 1, то лучше использовать radiobutton, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio, посмотрите примеры в MDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```css
.colors {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ddd;
}

.colors input { 
  display: none;
}

.colors label {
  display: block;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colors label:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.colors label[for="c1"] {background: red;}
.colors label[for="c2"] {background: orange;}
.colors label[for="c3"] {background: yellow;}
.colors label[for="c4"] {background: green;}
.colors label[for="c5"] {background: aqua;}
.colors label[for="c6"] {background: blue;}
.colors label[for="c7"] {background: violet;}

#c1:checked ~ label[for="c1"],
#c2:checked ~ label[for="c2"],
#c3:checked ~ label[for="c3"],
#c4:checked ~ label[for="c4"],
#c5:checked ~ label[for="c5"],
#c6:checked ~ label[for="c6"],
#c7:checked ~ label[for="c7"] {
  border: 2px solid #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <input type="radio" id="c1" name="c" value="red"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c2" name="c" value="orange"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c3" name="c" value="yellow"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c4" name="c" value="green"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c5" name="c" value="aqua"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c6" name="c" value="blue"/>
  <input type="radio" id="c7" name="c" value="violet"/>
  <!--  -->
  <label for="c1" title="red"></label>
  <label for="c2" title="orange"></label>
  <label for="c3" title="yellow"></label>
  <label for="c4" title="green"></label>
  <label for="c5" title="aqua"></label>
  <label for="c6" title="blue"></label>
  <label for="c7" title="violet"></label>
</div>
```

Или можно чуть сократить код CSS, если изменить разметку на более традиционную, но менее удобочитаемую:

```css
.colors {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ddd;
}

.colors input { display: none; }

.colors label {
  display: block;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #222;
}

[for="c1"] { background: red; }
[for="c2"] { background: orange; }
[for="c3"] { background: yellow; }
[for="c4"] { background: green; }
[for="c5"] { background: aqua; }
[for="c6"] { background: blue; }
[for="c7"] { background: violet; }

[name="c"]:not(:checked) + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <input type="radio" id="c1" name="c" value="red" />
  <label for="c1" title="red"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="c2" name="c" value="orange" />
  <label for="c2" title="orange"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="c3" name="c" value="yellow" />
  <label for="c3" title="yellow"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="c4" name="c" value="green" />
  <label for="c4" title="green"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="c5" name="c" value="aqua" />
  <label for="c5" title="aqua"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="c6" name="c" value="blue" />
  <label for="c6" title="blue"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="c7" name="c" value="violet" />
  <label for="c7" title="violet"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Если изменить разметку на более традиционную, то CSS можно подсократить. Можно добавить вариант прямо в ваш ответ? (Всё равно он на основе вашего).

Comment: @UModeL, я не против, но почему не как свой ответ, галочку получите?)

Comment: @DeMinov: там только моя правка, а идея и код ваши. Не люблю, когда копируют твой ответ и, добавив пару запятых, выдают за свой совершенно уникальный ответ.

Comment: Простите, господа, я по заданию не совсем понял какая картинка должна меняться при клике? Сам выделяемый элемент?

Comment: @BearVorkuta, в целом я тоже ничего не понял про картинку: на скриншоте её нет, в тексте сказано, что она меняется, в коде её видно, но не понятно как, куда и на что она должна меняться. Опять же в вопросе больше уточнений о инпутах и их выборах, вот и ответ